# dnn 7+ search is not indexing custom module items

Tags: vb.net, lucene, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7

I have a dnn 7.2.2 development site running under dnndev.me on my local machine.  I have created a simple product catalogue module and am trying to integrate the new search for dnn 7.

Here is the implementation of ModuleSearchBase in my feature/business controller

```
Imports DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules
Imports DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions
Imports DotNetNuke.Services.Search
Imports DotNetNuke.Common.Globals

Namespace Components

    Public Class FeatureController
        Inherits ModuleSearchBase
        Implements IUpgradeable


        Public Overrides Function GetModifiedSearchDocuments(moduleInfo As ModuleInfo, beginDate As Date) As IList(Of Entities.SearchDocument)

         Try

            Dim SearchDocuments As New List(Of Entities.SearchDocument)

            'get list of changed products
            Dim vc As New ViewsController
            Dim pList As List(Of vw_ProductList_Short_Active) = vc.GetProduct_Short_Active(moduleInfo.PortalID)

            If pList IsNot Nothing Then
                ''for each product, create a searchdocument
                For Each p As vw_ProductList_Short_Active In pList

                    Dim SearchDoc As New Entities.SearchDocument

                    Dim ModID As Integer = 0
                    If p.ModuleId Is Nothing OrElse p.ModuleId = 0 Then
                        ModID = moduleInfo.ModuleID
                    Else
                        ModID = p.ModuleId
                    End If

                    Dim array() As String = {"mid=" + ModID.ToString, "id=" + p.ProductId.ToString, "item=" + Replace(p.Name, " ", "-")}
                    Dim DetailUrl = NavigateURL(moduleInfo.TabID, GetPortalSettings(), "Detail", array)

                    With SearchDoc
                        .AuthorUserId = p.CreatedByUserId
                        .Body = p.ShortInfo
                        .Description = p.LongInfo
                        .IsActive = True
                        .PortalId = moduleInfo.PortalID
                        .ModifiedTimeUtc = p.LastUpdatedDate
                        .Title = p.Name + " - " + p.ProductNumber
                        .UniqueKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
                        .Url = DetailUrl
                        .SearchTypeId = 2
                        .ModuleId = p.ModuleId
                    End With

                    SearchDocuments.Add(SearchDoc)
                Next

                Return SearchDocuments

            Else
                Return Nothing
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            LogException(ex)
            Return Nothing
        End Try

        End Function
    End Class

End Namespace
```

I cleared the site cache and then I manually started a search re-index.  I can see from the host schedule history that the re-index is run and completes.

### PROBLEM

None of the items in the above code are added to the index.  I even used the Luke Inspector to look into the lucene index and that confirms that these items are not added.

### QUESTION

I need help figuring out why these items are not getting added or I need help on how to debug the indexing to see if anything is going run during that process.

Thanks in Advance

JK

### EDIT #1

I ran the following procedure in Sql Server to see if the module is even listed in the search modules:

```
exec GetSearchModules[PortalId]
```

The module in question does appear in this list.  The indexing is called for the featureController, but the results are not added to the lucene index.  Still need help.

### EDIT #2

So I upgraded to 7.3.1 in the hopes that something during the installation would fix this issue.  But it did not.  The search documents are still getting created/ returned by the GetModifiedSearchDocuments function but the documents are not being added to the Lucene index and therefore do not appear in the search results.

### EDIT #3

The break point is not getting hit like i thought after the upgrade, but I added a try catch to log exceptions and the following error log is getting created when I try to manually re-index (cleaned up to keep it short)

```
AssemblyVersion:7.3.1
PortalID:-1
PortalName:    
DefaultDataProvider:DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke
ExceptionGUID:d0a443da-3d68-4b82-afb3-8c9183cf8424
InnerException:Sequence contains more than one matching element
Method:System.Linq.Enumerable.Single
StackTrace:
Message:
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one matching element
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at DotNetNuke.Services.Scheduling.Scheduler.CoreScheduler.LoadQueueFromTimer()
   at DotNetNuke.Services.Scheduling.Scheduler.CoreScheduler.Start()
Source:
Server Name: KING-PC
```

### EDIT #4

Okay, I fixed the problem in edit three following [This Disucssion on the DNN issue tracker](https://dnntracker.atlassian.net/browse/DNN-5474),  but still no items being added to the lucene index.

The breakpoint is hit, and once i leave the debugger running for a while i get the following error:

> {"Exception of type 'Lucene.Net.Index.MergePolicy+MergeException' was
>   thrown."} {"Cannot overwrite:
>   C:\websites\dnndev.me\App_Data\Search\_1f0.fdt"}

Looks like a permission error. I'll see what I can work out

Comment: If you attach to the process locally to Debug, are you able to hit this with a breakpoint?

Comment: i did have a casting error creating the url link, but once i fixed that the search documents are all crated and returned properly.  THe module definition also marks this module as searchable.  I'm not sure where to look now

Comment: Are you able to attach to the W3WP process and debug? Will it hit your breakpoint?

Comment: yes, when I hover the mouse over the breakpoint in visual studio it tells me that it is "in process 'w3wp.exe'"

Comment: @ChrisHammond, i upgraded to 7.3.1 and the breakpoints get hit, see edit#4 for detail about a new error generated

Comment: Not an answer, but there is a 4-part tutorial on DNN search integraion at DNNHero.com. You'll need a subscription.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

J King,

I just finished a series on DNNHero.com on [Implementing Search in your Module](http://www.dnnhero.com/Premium/Tutorial/tabid/259/ArticleID/307/Search-Integration-Implement-SearchModuleBase-Part-3-4.aspx).  Parts 3 and 4 are implementing and debugging your ModuleSearchBase implementation.

**EDIT: Remove your assignment to the SearchTypeId in your implementation**

Also, here is a sample snippet to see how i am setting the attributes of the SearchDocument.  Again, watch my video for a whole bunch of other potential pitfalls in the Search implementation.

```
        SearchDocument doc = new SearchDocument
        {
            UniqueKey = String.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}",
                    moduleInfo.ModuleDefinition.DefinitionName, moduleInfo.PortalID, item.ItemId),
            AuthorUserId = item.AssignedUserId,
            ModifiedTimeUtc = item.LastModifiedOnDate.ToUniversalTime(),
            Title = item.ItemName,
            Body = item.ItemDescription,
            Url = "",
            CultureCode = "en-US",
            Description = "DotNetNuclear Search Content Item",
            IsActive = true,
            ModuleDefId = moduleInfo.ModuleDefID,
            ModuleId = item.ModuleId,
            PortalId = moduleInfo.PortalID,
            TabId = tab
        };
```

Comment: It does seem that your 'Lucene.Net.Index.MergePolicy+MergeException' is a filesystem error. But it could be an issue with a UniqueKey collision with a SearchDocument with a different type.  I would change your UniqueKey assignment, go to the Search Admin and click the Re-index button.  Then go to the scheduler and run the Crawler task with your breakpoint in your method.  You should not get any exceptions and before it leaves your method you should have a good List of SearchDocument objects.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the uniqueKey to a new quid string and tried the procedure with and without the url.  The search documents are created just fine and returned just fine.  But they never get added to the index even after re-indexing and manually running the host sitecrawl task.  I am losing my mind here, I could not even find another reference to GetModifiedSearchDocuments in my local install of DNN 7.3.1 as an example.

Comment: The only other difference between the code I wrote for the tutorial and yours is that I am setting CultureCode, ModuleDefId, and TabId on the SearchDocument object.  I am NOT setting the SearchTypeId attribute.  Maybe try that?

Comment: i will, can you explain to me what the ModuleDefId is or point me to some documentation.  I caould not find anything that documents the parameters of GetModifiedSearchDocuments in the DNN wiki or anywhere else for that matter

Comment: Yes, ModuleDefId is the id of your module's definition (ie: the friendly name and all the attributes about your module in the manifest).  You simply set it with moduleInfo.ModuleDefID from the moduleInfo param DNN passes into your method.  This will tell the search that the "source" of the search document is from your module.

Comment: okay , so removing the searchTypeId fixed the problem, add it to your answer and I can accept it.  Thanks a lot.  I would still love to know if there is any documentation out there about this procedure

Comment: as a follow up: setting search type to 1 works as when I examine the lucene index with Luke I can see that 1 is the default value assigned when none is provided